# how to sum two value of two array just if both id is same

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array with different fields, first array is user information and second is users coupon number.

I want `total = (coupon_cnt * 1000) + liked_cnt` if two array id 's equal

I wrote this code but this wont return user info

```
         $input = array($like , $coupon);
         foreach ($input as $set) {
            array_walk($set, function($entry) use (&$output) {
                $count = array_pop($entry);
                $id = array_pop($entry);
                if (array_key_exists($id, $output)) {
                    $output[$id]['user_score'] += 1000 * $count;
                } else {
                    $output[$id] = ['id' => $id, 'user_score' => $count];
                }
            });
        }

        $score =  array_values($output);
```

**Arrays**

```
$like = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [user_phone] => 00000000
            [user_email] => test@gmail.com
            [user_name] => test
            [user_password] => test
            [user_city] => 1
            [user_picture] => V5XgNt6P3BhT9iucdv_photo_001.jp
            [user_coupon_token] => 43131
            [user_post_hour] => 10
            [user_is_block] => 0
            [user_reg_date] => 2017-05-16 13:52:35
            [last_ip] => 
            [user_push_token] => 
            [liked_cnt] => 6 <-- I want add this to coupon_cnt * 1000
        )
    )

$coupon = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [coupon_cnt] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [coupon_cnt] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 139
            [coupon_cnt] => 1
        )


)
```

**output**

```
$output = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 85
                [user_phone] => 00000000
                [user_email] => test@gmail.com
                [user_name] => test
                [user_password] => test
                [user_city] => 1
                [user_picture] => V5XgNt6P3BhT9iucdv_photo_001.jp
                [user_coupon_token] => 43131
                [user_post_hour] => 10
                [user_is_block] => 0
                [user_reg_date] => 2017-05-16 13:52:35
                [last_ip] => 
                [user_push_token] => 


                [output] => 2006 <-- I want this
            )
        )
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Also put your desire output

Comment: @RJParikh Code updated, please check, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First make the 2nd array a bit easier to manage:

```
$easierToManageSecondArray = array_column($coupon, "coupon_cnt", "id");
```

Then the "loop":

```
 $like = array_map(function ($value) use ($easierToManageSecondArray) {
        if (isset($easierToManageSecondArray[$value["id"]]) {
            $value["user_score"] = ($easierToManageSecondArray[$value["id"]] * 1000) + $value["liked_cnt"];
        } else {
             $value["user_score"] =  $value["liked_cnt"]; //No idea if this makes sense.
        }
        return $value;
 }, $like);
```

Comment: sorry, Whats the `$value` in the first row, I have error

Comment: `$value` would be a single array entry from the `$liked` array e.g.`$value = [ "id" => 85, "user_phone" => ... "liked_cnt" => X ]`

Comment: unfortunately not working :( `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli it should be on variable `$like` not the one I had put earlier ($liked) updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code:

```
$like = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'id' => 85,
            'user_phone' =>' 00000000',
            'user_email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'user_name' => 'test',
            'user_password' => 'test',
            'liked_cnt' => 6 
        )
    );

$coupon = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'id' => 85,
            'coupon_cnt' => 2
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'id' => 86,
            'coupon_cnt' => 1
        )
);

foreach($like as $key => $value){
    foreach($coupon as $value2){
        if($value['id'] === $value2['id']){
            $like[$key]['liked_cnt'] += $value2['coupon_cnt'] * 1000;
        }               
    }
}

print_r($like);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [user_phone] =>  00000000
            [user_email] => test@gmail.com
            [user_name] => test
            [user_password] => test
            [liked_cnt] => 2006
        )

)
```

**Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/822418)**

Comment: I have made similar example. Please check it and let me know if anything. @Masoud Tavakkoli

Comment: Dear @RJParikh, its Ok and working well but the problem of this code is time of execution. I wrote a similar code but it take a long time to respond becuase my arrays are so BIG!!!. Anyway Thanks for your answer